# GLSL multitexturing twoo images

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I wrote this code:

```
"    vec3 col1 = texture2D(uDiffuseTexture, vec2(vTextureCoord.x, vTextureCoord.y + time)).rgb;\n" +
"    float a1=1.0;\n"+  
"    vec3 col2 = texture2D(uNormalTexture, vec2(vTextureCoord.x + time, vTextureCoord.y)).rgb;\n" +
"    float a2=uAlpha;\n"+
```

by the way:

with: `gl_FragColor = vec4(col1+col2, a1+a2);`

alpha not working...why? always the same, why?

my `uAlpha` variable is an `uniform`, that changes from 0.1 to 1.0

Comment: *alpha not working...* What is the result you're expecting ? Your `a1+a2` result is in the [1.1,2.0] range which is unusual for an alpha value.

Comment: i d like to draw image1 with 100%, and image2 with 0-100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i d like to draw image1 with 100%, and image2 with 0-100%

Currently, you're mixing your two images with additive blending (col1+col2) without considering the `uAlpha` uniform to mix the two images.

I suppose that what you're trying to achieve is blend image2 over image1, using uAlpha as opacity.

```
vec3 col1 = texture2D(uDiffuseTexture, vec2(vTextureCoord.x, vTextureCoord.y + time)).rgb;
vec3 col2 = texture2D(uNormalTexture, vec2(vTextureCoord.x + time, vTextureCoord.y)).rgb;
float a2=uAlpha;
vec3 result = mix(col1, col2, a2);   // this combines the two texture colors
gl_FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
```